# Checking printing quota on Unix network

Tags: unix, printing, quota

We have been told we are allowed to print up to 100 pages per month on our account on the departments network, but since we have seen some enormous batches being printed, and since we have no indication of that quota, we are beginning to think that it is a bluff to prevent us from abusing the available resources.

Is there a way to check if there is a quota on printing pages, what is it, and how many pages are left on Unix systems? In particular we are using CentOS.

I didn't find any useful-looking function in `help`, but I have ran functions not listed there in the past, and since Unix commands have so cryptic names it's likely that I just didn't recognize anything. Also searching the web turned up guides for specific universities which use their own specific platform, so no luck there either.

Comment: If the printer has a way of 'seeing' your username, or if you need to enter a unique pin to use it, then yes, they can see the number of pages you've printed.

Comment: Indeed, we can check the printing queues through terminal, it displays username and document name as well as an id, so the system can definitely keep track. Not to mention that being on a lab network everything passes through the central server. The question is if there is a way to see what's logged ourselves, specifically the number of pages

Comment: That, I cannot answer; my knowledge doesn't cover that, but I won't leave a comment unanswered. Hopefully someone else may find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking post-grads in the lab, I found one who said that on all Unix systems the `pages` command returns the number of available pages for printing. It does require that you are logged into the server (with `ssh` in my case). Performing the `ssh` is required even from the network terminals, directly running it on a terminal in the computer you are using will not find the command.